# Placing Checkers pieces on a chessboard with `chessboard`, maybe using `xcolor`?

Tags: color, chess, chessboard

I would like to draw positions of Checkers (aka Draughts) with the almighty package `chessboard`, and I would like to place some discs with a nice boundary, rather than plain discs.

**Edit:** What I ideally need is a symbol for a checkers piece as follows, quoting from the documentation of `chessboard` regarding adding non-standard pieces on the board:

> Symbols should be scalable, so you should either use symbols from a
> font or use some resizing command from the graphicx package.

And then gives the following example (the minimal one, with a black clubsuit, is highlighted):
[image]

So yes, I would like something to replace `\clubsuit` with some nice checkers piece :)

---

The best example I found online is at the very end of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555137
where Marjin proposes to put a double border on plain discs.

I really like that effect, but I can't reproduce it. I simply put this code in my preamble (with `xcolor` loaded):

```
\definecolor{offwhite}{RGB}{255,255,244}
\definecolor{dimgray}{RGB}{42,42,42}
\newcommand{\blackdisc}{\linethickness{0.5mm}\color{dimgray}\circle*{19}\color{gray}\circle{19.4}\linethickness{0.2mm}\circle{15}}
\newcommand{\whitedisc}{\linethickness{0.5mm}\color{offwhite}\circle*{19}\color{gray}\circle{19.4}\linethickness{0.2mm}\circle{15}}
```

Which is then used to have the following result:
[image]

Note that the original code used `\renewcommand` rather than `\newcommand`, because it was used within the `othelloboard` environment.

I just tried to write `\blackdisc` in text mode, but I get the disc and the boundary uncentered, so I haven't gone forward to use it within `chessboard`.

Is there an easy fix to this, or an alternative solution?

Comment: well while I like to hear that chessboard is almighty I don't like questions which contains only snippets of code and links to other questions. I don't have the time to hunt through links and assemble code.

Comment: I only mentioned the relevant code, the rest was specific to `othelloboard` - I added a picture from the linked question for clarity

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if you provided a code example, but the `\blackdisk` code you show is picture mode so it is designed to be used inside `\begin{picture}(10,10)\put(0,0){\blackdisk}}\end{picture}` or some such construct.

Answer (score 4):

This is an alternative solution, I don't know if your problem can be fixed with the `chessboard` package (I have never used it). But it's very easy to draw a checkers game with Ti*k*Z and put the pieces where you need them. I am drawing the pieces with a `\pic`, the rest are squares.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm] {standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/piece/.style={
    code={%
      \draw[line width=0.4mm,fill] (-0.5,-0.5) circle (0.4);
      \draw[line width=0.2mm]      (-0.5,-0.5) circle (0.3);
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% chessboard
\draw[very thick,brown] (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
\foreach\i in {0,...,7}\foreach\j in {0,...,7}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\blend{Mod(\i+\j,2)==0?75:25}
  \fill[brown!\blend] (\i,\j) rectangle ++ (1,1);
}
% black pieces
\foreach\i/\j in {1/1,3/1,5/1,7/1,2/2,4/2,6/2,8/2,/3,3/3,5/3,6/4}
  \pic[draw=white] at (\i,\j) {piece};
% white pieces
\foreach\i/\j in {2/8,4/8,6/8,8/8,1/7,3/7,5/7,7/7,2/6,4/6,6/6,8/6}
  \pic[fill=white] at (\i,\j)     {piece};
% an intruder
\pic[draw=red,fill=green] at (3.5,4.25) {piece};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** A slightly better looking piece:

```
\tikzset
{%
  pics/piece/.style={
    code={%
      \fill                   (-0.5,-0.5) circle (0.4);
      \fill[left color=white,
            right color=gray,
            opacity=0.6]      (-0.5,-0.5) circle (0.4);
      \draw[line width=0.4mm] (-0.5,-0.5) circle (0.4);
      \draw[line width=0.2mm] (-0.5,-0.5) circle (0.3);
    }},
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Juan, this is a very good-looking solution! However, I realised that I need to use `chessboard` because it provides a more minimalistic chessboard (I am drawing infinite chessboards, so I can't really add too many details); I'll edit the question to clarify that I need a way to draw a piece with graphicx, in order to use it within that package.